# Joomla Form Submission Issue

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have RS form Pro installed. I created a from and when that submits i have changed the Form Action to another site where the form data is processed and then i return back to my joomla site.

`Form Location : www.myjoomlasite.com/index.php`

`Form Properties -> Form Attributes -> Action = www.mysite.com/process.php`

`Return URL= www.myjoomlasite.com/index.php`

What the issue is when the user submits form from `www.myjoomlasite.com/index.php` the Action for the Form is `www.mysite.com/process.php`, The process file is getting values correctly but i do not get any Form Submission values in My RS from Component. How would this process go in joomla so that i get data on both sites.

Answer (score -1):

you should use appropriate controller to process the form and by using `"www.mysite.com/process.php"` you are making extra entry point which may be vulnerable.

And to process form in controller. Following link will actuate the desired controller.

`www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_component&controller=myController`

For detail [JOOMLA MVC](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Introduction)